# Using Tags in an Extension Help Joomla

Tags: joomla, tags, custom-component

I´m trying to have a **Tag Field** in my **custom component joomla** but i just cant do it!,

I have followed this guide https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension#Creating_the_record but still could not do it, can someone try to explain little bit more on this.

Thank You for all incoming help(I'm desperate :))
I tried but I had a lot of errors and i'm a newbie in joomla, i just want the tag field in my custom component.

## **EDIT**

So I started here because I didn't understand the rest https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension#Modify_your_component.27s_table_class_.28or_classes_if_you_have_multiple_tables.29

**1º** I added this:

```
$this->_observers = new JObserverUpdater($this); JObserverMapper::attachAllObservers($this);
```

To my: 
**admin/tables/projectinfo.php**(I dont know if his that to do) http://prntscr.com/jf84sb

Code: http://prntscr.com/jf8ac2

**2º** Then: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension#Add_tags_to_the_getItem.28.29_method_of_the_model I didn't had that because is for joomla 3.1.4. ????

**3º** https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension#Add_a_tag_field_to_edit_screens This i think is Ok :D

**4º** https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension#Prepare_the_view i didn't not under stand a thing, i just Ctrl-P to the:

**admin\views\projectinfo\view.html.php**

and put it here:

```
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  com_projectinfo
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2018 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

/**
 * ProjectInfo View
 *
 * @since  0.0.1
 */
class ProjectInfoViewProjectInfo extends JViewLegacy
{
    /**
     * View form
     *
     * @var         form
     */
    protected $form = null;

    /**
     * Display the PROJECTINFO view
     *
     * @param   string  $tpl  The name of the template file to parse; automatically searches through the template paths.
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
    /*THIS LINE*/ $item->tags = new JHelperTags;
    $item->tags->getItemTags('com_projectinfo.projectinfo' , $this->item->id);/*THIS LINE*/
        JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "/administrator/components/com_projectinfo"
                                          . "/models/fields/js/catch.js");
        // Get the Data
        $this->form = $this->get('Form');
        $this->item = $this->get('Item');
        $this->script = $this->get('Script');
        // Check for errors.
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
        {
            JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));

            return false;
        }


        // Set the toolbar
        $this->addToolBar();

        // Display the template
        parent::display($tpl);

        // Set the document
        $this->setDocument();

        $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags');
        echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags);

    }

    /**
     * Add the page title and toolbar.
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   1.6
     */
    protected function addToolBar()
    {
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

        // Hide Joomla Administrator Main menu
        $input->set('hidemainmenu', true);

        $isNew = ($this->item->id == 0);

        if ($isNew)
        {
            $title = JText::_('COM_PROJECTINFO_MANAGER_PROJECTINFO_NEW');
        }
        else
        {
            $title = JText::_('COM_PROJECTINFO_MANAGER_PROJECTINFO_EDIT');
        }

        JToolBarHelper::title($title, 'projectinfo');
        JToolBarHelper::save('projectinfo.save');
        JToolBarHelper::cancel(
            'projectinfo.cancel',
            $isNew ? 'JTOOLBAR_CANCEL' : 'JTOOLBAR_CLOSE'
        );
    }
    /**
     * Method to set up the document properties
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setDocument() 
    {
        $isNew = ($this->item->id < 1);
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->setTitle($isNew ? JText::_('COM_PROJECTINFO_PROJECTINFO_CREATING') :
                JText::_('COM_PROJECTINFO_PROJECTINFO_EDITING'));
        $document->addScript(JURI::root() . $this->script);
        JText::script('COM_PROJECTINFO_PROJECTINFO_ERROR_UNACCEPTABLE');
    }

}
```

After this i was so confused and lot of errors i quit, the last one was this:

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla_3.8.7-Stable-Full_Package\administrator\components\com_projectinfo\views\projectinfo\view.html.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined property: ProjectInfoViewProjectInfo::$item in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla_3.8.7-Stable-Full_Package\administrator\components\com_projectinfo\views\projectinfo\view.html.php on line 36

Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla_3.8.7-Stable-Full_Package\administrator\components\com_projectinfo\views\projectinfo\view.html.php on line 36

ty

Comment: post some code which you have tried and also issue which you face while implementation.

Comment: ok, wait a bit :D

Comment: @raVan96 done, i've edited the question

Comment: Yes Looking into it , Will be back soon :)

Comment: Just Question Are you want to use Tag field in Joomla form or You need tag system in component . So both things are different

Comment: tag system in my component  @raVan96

Comment: This question seems more appropriately posted at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.   You might like to custom flag this question for migration.